# jQuery resize and on document ready combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have this JS function to remove the class from dependable on screen size. It works 
 only when you resize the screen (Which I believe is expected behavior), however, I need to get this working on load too.

```
require(['jquery'], function(){
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        var innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
        if (innerWidth < 800) {
            jQuery("#logo-container").removeClass('pull-left');
        } else if (innerWidth > 800) {
            jQuery("#logo-container").addClass('pull-left');
        }
    });
});
```

I wrapped the function with document.ready and added the same content before the resize event. Now have something like this:

```
require(['jquery'], function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
        if (innerWidth < 800) {
            jQuery("#logo-container").removeClass('pull-left');
        } else if (innerWidth > 800) {
            jQuery("#logo-container").addClass('pull-left');
        }
        jQuery(window).resize(function() {
            var innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
            if (innerWidth < 800) {
                jQuery("#logo-container").removeClass('pull-left');
            } else if (innerWidth > 800) {
                jQuery("#logo-container").addClass('pull-left');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Now, my function's results are what I want, however, I feel like I am repeating my code.

**Is this the correct way of doing this? Is there a better alternative method?**

*Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.*

Comment: you can resize by creating new function and calling it in each condition to prevent rewriting all statments again

Comment: Add one function and call it..

Comment: I see! Got my answer now! Thank you for the help received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Avoid duplicate code.**

Make one function and call it on document ready function and window resize function...

> In the below code, all the code goes to `OnScreenResized()` function.

```
require(['jquery'], function() {
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        OnScreenResized();

      });

      jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        OnScreenResized();
      });

      function OnScreenResized() {
        var innerWidth = window.innerWidth;

        if (innerWidth < 800) {
          jQuery("#logo-container").removeClass('pull-left');
        } else if (innerWidth > 800) {
          jQuery("#logo-container").addClass('pull-left');
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: ahhh great! Thanks for your help and advice!

Answer (score 1):

Something to remember, if you ever need to copy and paste the exact same code block, it is always a good time to refactor it into function calls:

```
require(['jquery'], function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(window).resize(function() {
            toggleClass();
        });
        toggleClass();
    });

    function toggleClass() {
        var innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
        if (innerWidth < 800) {
            jQuery("#logo-container").removeClass('pull-left');
        } else if (innerWidth > 800) {
            jQuery("#logo-container").addClass('pull-left');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: that's great! Thanks for you help and advice.